# Build Tar file from directory in PHP without exec/passthru

Tags: php, linux, backup, archive

So I have a client who's current host does not allow me to use tar via exec()/passthru()/ect and I need to backup the site periodicly and programmaticly so is there a solution?

This is a linux server.

Comment: Seems like an odd limitation.

Comment: But not entirely on common, many hosts just block the usage entirely instead of chjail'ing users.

Comment: Right, but it is silly, given the power of PHP to interact with the filesystem.

Comment: I was curious about this because I want a cross-platform solution that works on Windows as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At http://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Tar you can donload the PEAR tar package and use it like this to create the archive:

```
<?php
require 'Archive/Tar.php';
$obj = new Archive_Tar('archive.tar');
$path = '/path/to/folder/';
$handle=opendir($path); 
$files = array();
while(false!==($file = readdir($handle)))
 {
    $files[] = $path . $file;
 }

if ($obj->create($files))
 {
    //Sucess
 }
else
 {
    //Fail
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 20):

PHP 5.3 offers a much easier way to solve this issue.

Look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/phardata.buildfromdirectory.php

```
<?php
$phar = new PharData('project.tar');
// add all files in the project
$phar->buildFromDirectory(dirname(__FILE__) . '/project');
?>
```

Comment: This will not work if you have empty directories (will be omitted), symlinks (omitted) or broken symlinks (throws exception), but will include empty directories that are symlink targets - go figure. So in 98% of the cases it's a good solution, and the rest of the times it's a great way to shoot yourself in the foot!

Answer (score 4):

There is the [Archive_Tar](http://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Tar) library. If that can't be used for some reason, the [zip](http://php.net/zip) extension might be another option.

Comment: You posted while I was typing but I'll keep mine here since it has the code.

Answer (score 0):

I need a solution that would work on Azure websites (IIS) and had trouble with creating new files on the server using methods from other answers. The solution that worked for me was to use small [TbsZip](http://freecode.com/projects/tbszip-a-zip-modifier-for-php) library for compression, which doesn't require to write file anywhere in the server - it's just returned directly via HTTP.

This thread is old, but  this approach might be a bit more generic and complete answer, so I post the code as alternative:

```
// Compress all files in current directory and return via HTTP as a ZIP file
// by buli, 2013 (http://buli.waw.pl)
// requires TbsZip library from http://www.tinybutstrong.com

include_once('tbszip.php'); // load the TbsZip library
$zip = new clsTbsZip(); // instantiate the class
$zip->CreateNew(); // create a virtual new zip archive

// iterate through files, skipping directories
$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.'));
foreach($objects as $name => $object)
{ 
    $n = str_replace("/", "\\", substr($name, 2)); // path format
    $zip->FileAdd($n, $n, TBSZIP_FILE); // add fileto zip archive
}

$archiveName = "backup_".date('m-d-Y H:i:s').".zip"; // name of the returned file 
$zip->Flush(TBSZIP_DOWNLOAD, $archiveName); // flush the result as an HTTP download
```

And here's the whole [article on my blog](http://buli.waw.pl/compress-files-ftp-php).