# Does PHP have a tar like function?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Build Tar file from directory in PHP without exec/passthru](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333130/build-tar-file-from-directory-in-php-without-exec-passthru)

Does PHP have a tar like function? So that I can create a tar file containing some dirs just created?

Comment: So Shall I say sorry for the duplicate? I am not good at English, Maybe not have a keyword to search this kind of question? So dislike??? All the same, thank you!

Comment: No worries, just try searching first when you have questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Archive_Tar](http://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Tar/redirected) will do this for you. You should know that this only makes a file that contains a lot of files; they aren't compressed at all. Consider compressing with gzip for text data or bzip for binary data.

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you like to tell me if there is a independence package like Archive_Tar? I think it's not easy to install Pear in our host.

Comment: I guess you might try calling tar directly using exec - http://php.net/exec but your host might not allow it.

Comment: Also be sure to check your inputs to exec and be careful about what a user can set because they could inject malicious commands into your web server. Developer beware.

Comment: OK, I believe you give me a solution about using tar in PHP. Thank you!